# Jdbc распарсивание двух массивов и добавление в БД

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данной форме в Поля Authors и Keywords вносятся слова через пробел.
Как распарсить сразу 2 массива и передать их в бд одним запрсом, если это возможно?

пытался вот так:

```
  connection = connector.getConnection();
        query = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT INTO document_s (document_id, document_name, document_type, creation_date, parent_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        query.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
        query.setString(2, docid.getDoc_name());
        query.setString(3, docid.getDoc_type());
        query.setString(4, docid.getCreation_date());
        query.setInt(5, docid.getParent_id());

        query.executeUpdate();
        resultSet = query.getGeneratedKeys();
        resultSet.next();
        int key = resultSet.getInt(1);
        query1 = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT INTO document_r(index, document_id, authors, keywords) VALUES(?,?,?,?));
        query1.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
        query1.setInt(2, key);
        query1.setString(3, docid.getAuthors());
        query1.setString(4, docid.getKeywords());
        query1.executeUpdate();
        return 0;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connector.close1(connection, query, resultSet);
    }
    return 0;
```

Я подразумеваю, что нужно сделать через цикл `for` как здесь:

```
  for (String retval: s.split(" ")) {
  query1.setString(1, retval);
  query1.executeUpdate();
  }
```

это нужно сделать сразу для двух строк.

В итоге должно получиться так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Хелп

Comment: Вы получили три автора и четыре кейворда. Что Вы с ними будете делать?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov 
вводить в базу данных в Таком формате
1 1 evg bas ||
2 1 ref nas  ||
3 1 gef mas ||
4 1       ras  ||

Comment: Т.е. в базе добавится 3*4=12 записей?

Comment: @a
4 Записи я отформатировал верхный комментарий

Comment: @AntonShchyrov отредактировал в конце скрин как должно выглядеть В конце

Comment: Отсутствующее значение заполняется как `NULL` или как пустая строка?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov как NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//int key = ?;
String[] autors = docid.getAuthors().split( " " );
String[] keywords = docid.getKeywords().split( " " );
for ( int i = 0; i < Math.max( autors.length, keywords.lenght ); i++ ) {
   query.setInt( 1, i+1 );
   query.setInt( 2, key );
   if ( i >= autors.length ) {
       query.setNull( 3, Types./*N*/VARCHAR );
   } else {
       query.setString( 3, autors[i] );
   }
   if ( i >= keywords.length ) {
       query.setNull( 4, Types./*N*/VARCHAR );
   } else {
       query.setString( 4, keywords[i] );
   }
   query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: при таком раскладе выдает ошибку No value specified for parameter 3
в дебаге он просто пролетает это

Comment: @Евгений Сложно сказать в чем дело - какие входные данные, на котором `i` происходит, нет ли опечаток, поддерживает ли драйвер все типы данных?

Comment: была опечатка, только теперь у меня sql Говорит что ошибка в запросе хотя то же самое в сам Mysql прописываю и проходит а JDBC говорит Achtung
index, document_id, authors, keywords) VALUES(1,54,'evg','sda')

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] authors = docid.getAuthors().split(" ");
String[] keywords = docid.getKeywords().split(" ");
int minLen = Math.min(authors.length, keywords.length);

for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
  query1.setString(3, authors[i]);
  query1.setString(4, keyword[i]);
  query1.executeUpdate();
}

query1.setNull(3, Types.STRING);
for (int i = minLen; i < keywords.length; i++) {
  query1.setString(4, keyword[i]);
  query1.executeUpdate();
}

query1.setNull(4, Types.STRING);
for (int i = minLen; i < authors.length; i++) {
  query1.setString(3, authors[i]);
  query1.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: а разве после каждой setString нужно делать update?
Мне ведь нужно получается чтобы делался insert строки с первыми значениями, потом insert со вторыми и т.д

Comment: @Евгений Ну так так и получится. `setString` устанавливает значение параметра `executeUpdate` выполняет запрос с указанными параметрами на сервере